# xcode: printf в C, не работает без переноса строки

Tags: c++, c, xcode

Наблюдается только в среде xcode , в языках C и С++, вывод происходит только если дописывать `\n` или `endl` в конце каждого вывода.

Например в таком коде вывода просто не происходит.

```
void print_char(char c){
    unsigned char mask = 128;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        printf("%s",((mask & c)?"1":"0"));
        mask >>= 1; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ну так: как и должно быть. Почему вас это удивляет? Вывод, разумеется, происходит. Но на терминале сразу не появляется.

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего дело в буферизации вывода. Вызывайте [`fflush(stdout)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush) после [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). Про буферизацию можно прочитать, например, в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Comment: Три раза перечитал этот ответ и, вдруг, понял, в чём заключается вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

Надо сделать вот так:

```
void print_char(char c){
    unsigned char mask = 128;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        printf("%s",((mask & c)?"1":"0"));
        mask >>= 1; 
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```